# How to split correct and incorrect answers

Tags: php

Code below separates correct letters and incorrect letters from each other if option type is letter. E.g If option type is A-D and correct letter is B, then it removes B from A B C D using the `$wrong` variable making it A C D for `$incorrect_ans` variable.

Now what I want to do is that if option type is `Yes or No` and correct answer is `Yes`, then it should separate `Yes` from `Yes, No` so that I can display `No` in `incorrect_ans` variable. Problem is that at the moment it is not split both these options, so it is displaying bother this answers as incorrect answers when in this example `No` should be incorrect. But how can this be achieved?

I want the same to work for `True or False` option as well. As I mentioned my code works for letter answers, just not `Yes or No` or `True or False`.

Below is code:

```
$specialOptionTypes = array(
     'Yes or No'     => array('Yes', 'No'),
     'True or False' => array('True', 'False')
);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // Do this for each row:
    if (array_key_exists($dbOptionType, $specialOptionTypes)) {
        $options = $specialOptionTypes[$dbOptionType];
    } else if (preg_match('/^([A-Z])-([A-Z])$/', $dbOptionType, $match)) {
        $options = range($match[1], $match[2]);
    } else {
        // issue warning about unrecognized option type
        $options = array();
    }
    $right = $dbAnswer; // $right = 'True';
    $wrong = array_diff($options, $right);
    $incorrect_ans[] = $wrong;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If I had this data in database

Question Table:

```
QuestionId QuestionNo OptionId
11          1         3
12          2         26
```

Option_Table Table:

```
OptionId OptionType
1        A-C
2        A-D
3        A-E

..............

26       Yes or No
```

Answer Table:

```
AnswerId Answer QustionId
1        A      11
2        C      11
3        Yes    12
```

Ok so for Question 1 (look at tables closely), The option type ($OptionType) is `A-E` meaning by using code below:

```
(preg_match('/^([A-Z])-([A-Z])$/', $dbOptionType, $match)) {
        $options = range($match[1], $match[2]);
```

It displays these Options `A B C D E`.

Now Correct Answers for Question 1 is A and C (using `$right = $dbAnswer;`). So Split correct answers from incorrect answers using:

$wrong = array_diff($options, $right);

Then we are left with the incorrect answers which as `B D E`. These are stored in array using:

```
$incorrect_ans[] = $wrong;
```

Problem I have is that this does not work for `Yes or No` option in question 2. The incorrect answer is `No` and correct answer is `Yes` for question 2 but it does not split `Yes` and `No` as it displays them both as incorrect answers. This is incorrect.

Comment: this is very hard to follow, can you simplify it with a concrete example.

Comment: I have included update, is this helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code a bit

```php
$right = array($dbAnswer); // $right = array('True');
$incorrect_ans[] = array_diff( $options, $right );
```

The `array_diff` need both param be array. You can also `var_dump` the `$option` variable to be sure that it contains the right data.
Of course, the final `$incorrect_ans` array can contains both 'Yes' and 'No' because each is added when you fetch each row. **Each** element of `$incorrect_ans` contains the wrong answers of **the question it parsed from** . I think you should use the question ID as the key ob the `$incorrect_ans`, not just use the default numerical key.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you changed the code slightly. I thought you was giving me information but did not know you changed code to include array. Thanks it worked